# performance issue when SKScene is called by uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I'm new to spritebuiler.

I am getting performance issue when i tried to call skscene on uiviewconroller. i.e., I am developing a game on sprite kit.

My project has 2 view controllers named GameViewConroller, LevelSelectController & 2 SKScenes  named MainMenuScene & GameScene. MainMenuScene is called when app runs & it contains levelselect button & playbutton, if i press play button button it moves to Gamescene & game is played over here so animations I am plying in game scene are very  smooth and fine.

If i press levelselect button on MainMenuScene it moves to LevelSelectController it has 1 to 100 buttons  when i press any button it moves to GameScene and game is played over here so animations Im plying in GameScene are very  slow.

help me I am stuck !

```
   @implementation GameViewController
   - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
     [super viewDidLoad];

// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
/* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;

// Create and configure the scene.


SKScene *scene = [[MainMenuScene alloc] initWithSize:self.view.frame.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

   // Present the scene.
   [skView presentScene:scene];
   }
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: check it Ive added some code . this is how I am  calling the scenes

Comment: You need narrow down your issue. The code you posted is the standard present scene code and does not help identifying the problem.

Comment: Try testing it on a real device. Also, look into texture atlases.